Show the following forcing poset is $\sigma$-centered
In Kunen, there's the following exercise:
Assume MA(κ)
and (X,<)
be a total order with |X|≤κ
, then there are $a_x$⊂$ω$
such that if x<y
then $a_x$⊂∗$a_y$
. (x⊂∗y
if |x−y|<ω
and |y−x|=ω
.)
Hint. Let P
be a set of pairs (p,n)
, where p
is a partial function from X
to P(n)
and the domain of p
is finite. Define (p,n)≤(q,m)
iff domp⊇domq
, n≥m
, p(x)∩m=q(x)
for each x∈domq
and
∀x,y∈domq:x<y⟹p(x)−p(y)⊆m.
I solved the excercise and now I want to extend the result for any total order of size k<p, using Bell's Theorem, but I don't know how to show the forcing poset described is $\sigma$-centered.
Thanks in advance.

How did you show that the forcing is ccc, if not by showing that is $\sigma$-centered?
